# What am i missing Set-DynamicDistributionGroup

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to apply dynamic distribution group recipient filter to take the country into account

```
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -identity "HR - Everyone" -RecipientFilter {(CountryCore -eq 191) -and (RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (Company -eq "Contoso ltd")}
```

And i get the 'cannot be null' error, but the documentation says that only 'identity' is required, so i'm puzzled by this.

> Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. You cannot call
>   a method on a null-valued expression.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-DynamicDistributionGroup], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Set-DynamicDistributionGroup

Comment: I think you have a typo: `CountryCore` -> `CountryCode`. Please confirm if this resolves.

Comment: How did I not see that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its countryCode not CountryCore as written in your statement (looks like a typo).

Try:

```
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -identity "HR - Everyone" -RecipientFilter {(CountryCode -eq 191) -and (RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (Company -eq "Contoso ltd")}
```

Comment: Sometimes a 2nd person is needed ;-)